# Full screen page with JavaScript (Automatic)

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I need help making a webpage.  I need to set that page in fullscreen mode, so I have this JavaScript code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("fulscreen");
var fs = document.getElementById("body");
elem.onclick = function()
{
     req = fs.webkitRequestFullScreen;
     req.call(fs);
}
function toggleFullScreen()
{
     document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
}
```

Where "fulscreen" is a ID of a button and "body" is the ID of the HTML tag then all the page can be in full screen, but there is the problem, the fullscreen mode is activated when i do a click in the button, and I need the webpage in fullscreen automatically... thanks :)

Comment: I tried it and document ready too but didn't work!

Comment: `window.onload = function(){ // x functionality when window loads}`
not document.ready()!!

Comment: Something like this?



'window.onload = function(){
 var elem = document.getElementById("fulscreen");
    var fs = document.getElementById("body");

 req = fs.webkitRequestFullScreen;
    req.call(fs);
   function toggleFullScreen()
    {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
 }
}'

Answer (score 0):

http://sorcery.smugmug.com/2012/06/06/using-html5s-fullscreen-api-for-fun-and-profit/

Might help, though this function seems to be a morass of incompatibility.

Generally, in js if you want something to happen as soon as the page has loaded, put a call to it in

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp